# PDO Adaptive Server connection failed when connecting to MSSQL server in FuelPHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, fuelphp

FuelPHP seems to be doing something odd when I try to connect to a MSSQL database via PDO.

## Working Outside of FuelPHP

I have tried the following in a vanilla PHP page on my local server:

```
<?php
$mssql = new \PDO('dblib:host=<IP OF HOST>;dbname=<DBNAME>', '<USER>', '<PASS>');
```

And everything works fine. It connects and I can easily query the DB like I would expect.

## NOT Working Inside of FuelPHP

However, when I try adding the connection in config/db.php with basically the same information an exception is thrown.

```
<?php
return array(
  'mssql' => array(
    'connection'  => array(
      'dsn'        => 'dblib:host=<IP OF HOST>;dbname=<DBNAME>',
      'username'   => '<USER>',
      'password'   => '<PASS>',
    ),
    'type'        => 'pdo',
    'table_prefix' => '',
  ),
);
```

And subsequently try to query the DB within FuelPHP like so:

```
$q = \DB::select()
        ->from('table')
        ->limit(5);

$r = $q->execute('mssql');
```

The following exception is thrown: `Fuel\Core\Database_Exception [ 20002 ]: SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)`

What the kicker is when I try to just do my original basic connection inside of a controller of FuelPHP I get the same error message. So it appears FuelPHP is playing havoc with even a normal PDO connection.

### Example of basic connection attempt within a FuelPHP controller.

```
<?php

class Controller_Welcome extends Controller
{
  public function action_index()
  {
    $mssql = new \PDO('dblib:host=<IP OF HOST>;dbname=<DBNAME>', '<USER>', '<PASS>');
  }
}
```

For reference I am using PHP 5.3.16 and using FreeTDS to connect from my OS X laptop. (This shouldn't be an issue though since the vanilla version works.)

Comment: FYI: Fuelphp manages its connections internally and won't know about your 'off the grid' connection you created as a work-around.

Comment: Also worth noting: you should put your db config in the correct environment. Assuming this is the development environment, this probably should be in `/config/development/db.php`

Comment: Looking at it, I don't see anything obviously wrong.  Are you replacing 'dblib' with 'mssql' ?  Just making sure since its not represented like the other variables.

Comment: Coming back to this issue because I need to access MSSQL again and having the same problem. I'm NOT replacing dblib with mssql. In this case I am using it as a non default connection. The default is a mysql db which is already connected and I am trying to make a new connection to the mssql database.... Still no luck!